# Access Custom Page using Rally API (Example: Plan->Backlog)

Tags: java, rally

We have created a custom page called backlogs under "Plan" which contains prioritized tickets from our project. I would like to access these tickets through the API.

I would like to know which Object Model would give me these results.

Answer (score 1):

Custom pages and apps are not currently exposed via the API.  The closest thing you'll be able to do for now is to just duplicate the same queries your apps are doing in your java code.